# java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable code - bad operand types for binary operator '*'

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5QDi.png)
error description :
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable code - bad operand types for binary operator '*'
first type : int
second type : java.lang.object

Comment: Please replace your image with text.  It's not that hard

Comment: Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please learn about prepared statements and use those instead of writing insecure code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `spin1` is a `JSpinner` with a `SpinnerNumberModel`, you need to cast the result of `spin1.getValue()`:

```
total = harga * (int) spin1.getValue();
```

But your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should search on how to use `PreparedStatement`.